# Multiply out $y(2−y^3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I was multiplying out $y(2−y^3)$ would the answer be $2y-y^4$ or $2y-2y^3$.

I appreciate any insight on how to attempt to address this sort of question if I am completely off with this attempt.

Comment: What do you want to say????

Comment: I just said it in the question. I don't understand your question.

Comment: You have not used  MathJax in the expressions. So its difficult to understand.

Comment: it'll be 2 y-$y^4$

Comment: @user3081458, is the $3$ meant to be an exponent?  If so, put "y(2-y^3)" inside dollar signs.

Comment: Is it $y^3$ or $y\times 3$ or $y_3$?

Comment: If the user is asking a question a minute ago I don't understand why were votes down while try clarify it. It seems as if there is no tomorrow!

Comment: As a hint:  when in doubt about algebraic identities, plug in some values.  For example, taking $y=1$ in your product gives $1^*(2-1)=1^*1=1$.  Whatever the product is, it must give you $1$ when you plug in $y=1$.  Your first form does that, the second doesn't. That one example doesn't show that the first form is correct, but at least it eliminates the false form!

Comment: Sorry @Aniket I do not know how to use MathJax. I will learn to use it before I ask another question. Thank you all for your answers :)

Comment: You have to try learn and put effort in MathJax and mathematics to ask good questions @user3081458 You can search in Google *MathJax Tutorial*, too ask questions after you read your notes and try computations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you are looking for is the expansion of $ y(2-y^3) $

This gives $ 2y-y^4 $

Comment: And to be explicit: you distribute the factor $y$ over the two terms $2$ and $y^3$. Note that $y$ is the same as $y^1$, so the exponents add up: $$y\cdot(2-y^3)=(y\cdot 2)-(y\cdot y^3) =(y\cdot 2)-(y^1\cdot y^3)=2y-y^{1+3}=2y-y^4$$

Comment: Maybe explain a little better? $y(2-y^3)=y(2-y\times y\times y)=y\times 2-y\times y \times y\times y=2y-y^4$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, I really appreciate it. I understand now.

Comment: Maybe it’s even clearer as consequence of the general statement: $a(b+c)=ab+ac$.